# Drop Pin on Map with Direction Indicator?

Tags: ios, mapkit

We are developing IOS app. Where user can drop pin (Car, Bus etc) on map and define direction (angle) as well. I know how to drop pin but What I need to do for direction angle?

Here are details of my problem. As you can see a pin dropped at may. User can set direction to any angle with his fingers. Like user rotate photo. I need to show pin to other user app users to with exact direction angle. What I need to persist for that at central database or web API end that can be used to place that pin on other user's app. [image]

Comment: You can get angle with use of CCLocationManager heading, you need to startUpdateHeading with CCLocationManager

Answer (score 0):

`CLLocationManagerDelegate` protocol has a method called `- (void)locationManager:didUpdateHeading:` in which you can get a hold on users *heading* aka *direction*.

**Sample**:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading
{
    CLLocationDirection direction = newHeading.magneticHeading;
}
```

**NOTE**: for this method to be called, you have to call `CLLocationManager`'s instance method `- (void)startUpdatingHeading`. Like this:

```
[self.locationManager startUpdatingHeading];
```

Then if you have a custom view for `MKUserLocation` annotation you can rotate it based on previously received direction in above method.

**Sample**:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    {
        // rotated custom view code
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for prompt response. I have explained my problem with visual. Sorry for confusion. Can you suggest any thing now please?

Comment: @AdilFazal i don't really understand what you are trying to accomplish. Please refactor your question